# Discord.py bot fail to send message after certian amount

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord server and we wanted to implents a system that sends DM to user to announce about new activities and etc...
The server have around ~380 people in it.
I tried the bot first time in small server with friends for testing and it was working fine.
When I tried it our main server a lot of the memebers didnt get the message.
So when I tried it again I added something that print me the statistics of how many fails and
how many message was delivered. I know that some users will not receive DM if they blocked it in thier setting but when the bot finished to run I saw that only 54 was able to get the message and 335 failed. Moreover I know that people who got the message in the past didnt get this time.
I want to know if its the problem I have in the code and can be fixed.
In adittion it took around 15 min to send the message to everyone so if someone knows how can you run it a bit faster I would really appreciate it

the code:

```
@bot.command()
async def dm_all(ctx, *, args=None):
    if ctx.author.id != my_id:
        return
    counter, Gcounter, Fcounter = 0,0,0 
    if args is not None:
        members = ctx.guild.members
        for m in members:
          if(m.bot):
            continue
          counter=counter+1 
          await ctx.send('trying to send message to: ' + str(m.display_name))
          try:
            await m.send(args)
            await ctx.send("Message was send")
            Gcounter=Gcounter+1
          except:
              await ctx.send('didnt work')
              Fcounter=Fcounter+1
        await ctx.send("Send messaged to: " + str(Gcounter) +
        "\n failed to send to: " + str(Fcounter) + 
        "\n success rate is: " + str((Gcounter/counter)*100) + "%")
    else:
        await ctx.send('please provide a message')
```

Comment: Could you give more details on the exceptions you are receiving (i.e. what exceptions you are receiving, how many of each)?

Comment: Do you have the members intent enabled in the developer portal and in your `bot.intents`?

Answer (score 1):

**Your bot is being rate limited.**

Discord will prevent bots and users from sending too much data to their servers. (presumably to save bandwidth)

If you want to fix your problem add a delay between messages, I recommend a 1sec delay between messages.

Here's some code that will do that:

```
import time

@bot.command()
async def dm_all(ctx, *, args=None):
    if ctx.author.id != my_id:
        return
    counter, Gcounter, Fcounter = 0,0,0 
    if args is not None:
        members = ctx.guild.members
        for m in members:
          if(m.bot):
            continue
          counter=counter+1 
          await ctx.send('trying to send message to: ' + str(m.display_name))
          time.sleep(1)
          try:
            await m.send(args)
            await ctx.send("Message was send")
            Gcounter=Gcounter+1
          except:
              await ctx.send('didnt work')
              Fcounter=Fcounter+1
        await ctx.send("Send messaged to: " + str(Gcounter) +
        "\n failed to send to: " + str(Fcounter) + 
        "\n success rate is: " + str((Gcounter/counter)*100) + "%")
    else:
        await ctx.send('please provide a message')
```

It will take a while to send the message to all users, but there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Thank you I hope this the issuie I will not be able to check it now because we dont want to abuse this bot and spam our members hope next time we use it, it will work